How should I wire this TACO 501 to my old oil boiler?
I'm trying to slowly improve the energy efficiency of my home and I'm on a tight budget so I thought I'd start small and install a smart thermostat. However, I'm one of those unfortunate people who has a thermostat with only a R and W connection and while there is a blue (common) wire available, it's not hooked up to the zone control of the boiler, and therefore not useable to supply a constant 24V to a smart thermostat. I could jerry-rig some kind of relay etc. etc., but I'd rather just replace the zone controller since that's pretty old too. In short, how can I swap out my current (antique) Honeywell zone controller for a somewhat newer Taco 501?
My setup is as follows:

A Honeywell RA832A zone controller (it's on the older side)
This controller supplies power to a circulator as well as the aquastat control inside the boiler.
My aquastat control is also Honeywell (L4026B, vintage), which basically controls the boiler ignition and pump, and I should not need to do anything to it.

I've taken a few photographs (see below) and made a diagram to illustrate the current situation, but essentially a 120V supply is feeding the R832A and aquastat (coming in at the top of the zone controller housing), which in turn is controlling the boiler ignition and pump (both traveler/L wires); one wire from the aquastat is going to the R832A, connected on terminal 3. The N(eutral) is going to the second terminal on the R832A, the pump and boiler ignition. The thermostat is hooked up to the double T terminals and I believe the double X terminals (auxiliary) are unsuitable to supply a continuous 24V to the thermostat (basically to function as a common). The wires from inside the furnace enter the zone controller through the middle knockout; the pump wiring enters the zone controller through the knockout on the left.

Based on the instructions that came with the Taco 501 I imagine the new wiring would be as follows where I assume that the red from the aquastat is the common wire.

the incoming 120V hot will feed the Taco and the aquastat;
the Taco controls the pump based on signaling from the aquastat, wired up to 6 N(ormally)/O(pen) and 5 (common).
the incoming neutral is hooked up to the N on the Taco 501, pump and boiler ignition.

Unfortunately I have no wiring diagram for the aquastat (it's a hi-lo limiter) so I'm not 100% sure that red is the common (the blue may be as well though that does seem somewhat unlikely because the red terminal is right next to the hot going to the boiler).

The above is how I would wire up the Taco 501 to the aquastat and pump. Could anyone confirm if that looks correct?
Thanks!
Photographs






You need to be able to regard the boiler's "demand for heat" wires as an external interface, and all the circuitry that manages boiler temperature and ignition as inside a black box.  It's not an actual black box, you can see it and maintain it.  But replacing a thermostat should not get you into worrying about how the boiler's controller interfaces with its safety sensors and switches.  You should, I suggest you must, split this question into two.  1) If you want to replace anything "inside the box" -- set up that question CLEARLY. 2) Once that's done, worry about the thermostat.

Also be clear on the function of the "aquastat" -- is it a call for heat by a storage tank or a DHW circulator?  Or is it a hi/low limit switch that is part of the boiler design?

@jay613 Thanks for the reply, apologies if it's not clear what I'm looking to do, but I'm looking to swap out my current (antique) Honeywell zone controller for a somewhat newer Taco 501 so I can use it's com connection to provide a stable 24V current to my new smart thermostat. The aquastat, as you can see in the pictures, is a hi-lo limiter inside the boiler housing; I'll update the post. The circulator is toward the back, outside the boiler housing (its hot and neutral wire are coming in through the conduit you can see entering the Honeywell zone controller on the left).

what make/model is your boiler?

Great.  So.  For now, forget about the thermostat. Replace it with an on/off light switch for the purpose of "STEP 1" which is ensuring flow of gas, ignition, circulation, and water limit controls all work.  You need to use the documentation for your boiler, circulator, and aquastat to make sure you get this right, and you need to test it all.  Hi temp, low temp, low water, no circulation, no ignition, etc etc should all result in no gas!  Must test.  Don't complicate this by adding a new thermostat.  An on/off switch (or just a Wago) allows you to emulate a thermostat to do this.

@ron: no idea, it’s 60 years old. General Electric I think and it’s the rusty one

@jay I have no documentation for boiler or circulator—we just bought the house and the boiler is the original dating back to the 60s. However, the wiring doesn’t seem complex and some parts such as the aquastat have been replaced (they’re old, but not as old as the rest of the boiler). I was looking for how people generally wire up a Taco 501, but couldn’t find a wiring diagram except for what came with it. Does my diagram above look correct?

It does not look correct and with neither documentation nor experience I recommend you do not proceed. Figure out how to power your new thermostat without rewiring the high temp protection circuit in your boiler.

Briefly: If your goal is to power a smart thermostat, find a way to do that without touching the safety-critical circuits controlling the boiler. Do not replace the controller for no reason when you have neither the documentation for the components nor experience to do it correctly and test it. The cost/benefit for this is: Cost: you might die.  Benefit: None at all.
In more detail:
The job of the controller and aquastat are to:

Run the boiler when the thermostat calls for heat
Shut down the boiler when the water gets too hot
Run the circulator when the thermostat calls for heat
Keep running the circulator whenever the water is above a certain temperature regardless of the thermostat
Avoid rapidly cycling the boiler by maintaining a temperature differential for triggering both of the above functions.

In your top diagram, it appears the aquastat does ALL those things, and the controller is being used as a single 24V/120V relay with any other functionality being ignored.  Either your boiler does not have a low voltage control input (TT or RW) or you have left it out of your drawing.
In your second diagram, I'm not sure what you're doing.  Looks like you're connecting the aquastat's "run the circulator" signal back to the raw demand-for-heat signal from the controller.  Without the documentation I can't know for sure, I'm reading between the lines.  And the circulator being controlled directly by your new controller board.  This bypasses the aquastat's function #2 above --- IE, nothing stops your boiler overheating.  Maybe it has an internal mechanical device? Probably not!
Here is my answer: You want to use a smart thermostat.  You don't have experience wiring up the innards of a boiler, and you don't have documentation.   STAY OUT OF THERE.   All you need is 24V for the stat ... .figure it out.
Also, the Taco manual has a pin-to-pin mapping for various replacement controllers, including your own.    The very least you could do is just blindly follow that.  So in your top diagram there is only one signal wire connected - the red one - and in your bottom one that should be the only one connected, to the pin indicated by the table in the manual.   But I still suggest you do not do this.  Again: A LOT to lose, nothing to gain.
24V
The 24V Common in your controller is in the segment colored red here.  IF you can figure out how to access that, you can connect your blue thermostat wire to it.  Otherwise, there are other ways to get 24V to it, and that question has been asked many times on this site.
Note, your old controller is not designed to power a smart thermostat.   The power available to the stat is probably not documented, even if you had the document, which you don't.   It will probably work, but make sure it's delivering the amount of power required by the new stat, per its documentation.


just a brief response: the R832A provides the TT/RW to the boiler, as does the TACO501; nothing inside the boiler has or needs TT/RW. I'm not sure why my first diagram is not clear because that precisely lays out the current electrical connections from the unit into the boiler and to my circulator. All I'm looking to do is swap out one relay for another, rather than hotwiring something on the R832A's PCB (as you suggest) and I understand the need for testing, which I would obviously do, but all I would like to know from someone with electrical experience if my second diagram is correct.

I have electrical experience and your second diagram is not correct.   That is the answer to your question.   And you can ignore my further unsolicited advice but I reiterate that if you cannot see that for yourself, you should not be doing this work yourself.   You can replace the thermostat with relatively small risk, but not the controller.  You framed this whole thing with "energy efficiency" so I'm trying to help you achieve THAT, safely and easily.
